# drag and drop get position

Tags: javascript, html

I'm beeing stuck a bit and really could need some help with a project I'm working on.

First of all let me explain what I want to do.

I have a php site with 2 or more tables. Inside the tables are divs which allow the user to drop elements into them. So for example we have 1 empty table with 2 col and 2 rows and a second table with x elements in them(I get the elements from a database). The user is able to drag the elements from table2 and drop them inside table1. I managed to get that bit working, but in my next step I need to get the new position of the elements that have been dragged (or all elements on the site), so that I can save the new position in the database.

Table1 is build like this:

```
<table class="tg">
          <tr>
            <th class="tg-031e" colspan="2">Table 1</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tg-031e"><div class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
            <td class="tg-031e"><div class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tg-031e"><div class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
            <td class="tg-031e"><div class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
          </tr>
</table>
```

Table2 looks like this:

```
<table class="tg2">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e">table2</th>
  </tr>
    <?php
            $select = mysql_query($query_member);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_member)) {
            ?>
                <tr>
                   <td class="tg-031e"><div class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><div id="<?php echo $row['id']?>" class="dragitem" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><?php echo $row['name']?></div></div></td>
                </tr>

            <?php
            }
            ?>
</table>
```

So you can see I have a table, inside of it divs to allow items being dragged and dropped in them and the items themselfs are also inside a div.

My javascript for the drag and drop function:

```
<script>
   window.allowDrop = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (ev.target.getAttribute("draggable") == "true")
        ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "none";
    else
        ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "all";
};

window.drag = function(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("id", ev.target.id);
};

window.drop = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var id = ev.dataTransfer.getData("id");
    var dragged = document.getElementById(id);
    ev.target.appendChild(dragged);
    dragged.className += " dropped";
};
</script>
```

I'm trying for quite a while now to use javascript to get the position of the item inside the table. I thought it would be best to use the "ondrop" event for that, so as soon as an item is dropped I can update its position inside the sql table.

I tried something like this (just for testing)

```
alert(ev.parentNode.rowIndex);
```

inside the drop(event) function, but I simply cant get it to work >.<

Can someone please give me a helping hand and maybe explain me how I can do something like this? I'm just starting to learn javascript, but I really thought that would work.

I need the col and row of the div(inside the other div) inside the table.
If what I'm trying to do (in the way I'm doing it) is stupid, please tell me. I am really trying to learn and could need some guidance.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

```
ev.target.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex
```

Parent of the `div` is `td` but you need `tr` for `rowIndex`.

See Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pxLymxq1/

Comment: oh my god, its so easy that I feel bad for asking. Thanks alot.